# running a command for fixed time and getting output in a file

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to run a command for fixed time and get the output in a file.
getting output to a file can be done using `command > file`

and restricting a command to run only for fixed time can be done by `timeout 10 command`.

But `timeout 10 command > file` doesn't give any output in file.

Comment: `timeout 10 echo foo >bar` creates a file `bar` containing `foo` in my current working directory, so I guess the problem is in the command you're running. Please post the exact command you're running.

Comment: Are you sure your command is generating any output? Try running it without `> file`

Comment: hi @kos you tried the example " timeout 10 echo foo > bar ".Here the command echo bar takes less than 10 sec to terminate. So timeout is basically doing nothing.So it is writing to file.    try some command that run for more than 10s and give a timeout 10 to it.It is then not producing output in file.

Comment: @sinclair without >file , it is giving output in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> **quote from the comments:**
>
> the command echo bar takes less than 10 sec to terminate. So timeout is basically doing nothing.So it is writing to file.try some command that run for more than 10s and give a timeout 10 to it.It is then not producing output in file

This implies that you are testing with different commands.
You sadly do not provide the exact command you are trying to run.

Try to run this working example. If it works there is something wrong with your command.
Probably because it does not generate output at all or the output takes longer than the timeout.

**foo.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
  do
  echo foo;
  sleep 2
done
```

**command:**

```
timeout 10 ./foo.sh > foo.txt
```

**foo.txt:**

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Comment: I was trying to run "timeout 10 python3 -m speech_recognition > filename" which was not working.But I made a script file with command python3 -m speech_recognition and tried "timeout ./script.sh > filename" and it worked.